# Replace in-series incandescent lamps in a makeup mirror with LEDs

Tags: led, series, incandescent, replacement

This is my first post here.

My wife uses a makeup mirror which has 10 x BA9s in series. Each lamp is 3W 24V and since we are in Europe they run on AC 230V nominally (reading off a multimeter is sometimes 243V and even 248V).

A few months ago one of the original bulbs burnt out and the only local replacement I found were 24V 4W BA9S. Now every 4-5 weeks the 4W bulb burns out. I have marked the replaced bulb and it is always the one which burns out.

I thought of replacing all ten incandescent lamps with 24V LEDs from aliexpress. The ones I found are 2W and are meant to be used in vehicles.

My question is, would directly replacing the incandescent bulbs with LEDs lead to a worse situation if one of the SMD LEDs burns out?  Can I add some sort of resistor to the 4W incandescent so that the bulb voltage is somehow limited when the makeup mirror is switched on?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably worse If the LEDs are only DC,  and just as bad if AC in series which is non-linear.

Now the 4W lights probably are enclosed so they get hotter and reduce life from 3000h by 50% for every 10’C rise above open ambient. A Triac dimmer could solve that as well as a tiny low speed fan.  You could use 12V stripLED cut down to size and powered by 12Vdc 1A

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm afraid that adding a fan is out of the question as the space is very limited and as you rightly pointed out - enclosed. The LED strip is something I have thought about and will definitely look into.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 24V lamps I would use 28V lamps if you stick with incandescent. #1873 comes into mind. But yes you can get ac rated led bulbs. and i would use the ones with the built in current limiting if you go that direction. They will state a wide range of operation (6 Volt-28 Volt AC/DC I've seen) but they cost quite a bit more (around 4GBP)

Comment: Wow. 4GBP each would mean the lamps would probably cost more than a new complete mirror :-). I'll either try to source the original Babyliss lamps or else try to modify and use an led strip off a power supply. Thanks.

Comment: #1873 bulbs are not that expensive. And I would go 28V rating so that there is some surge headroom.

Comment: I have checked the #1873 bulbs out but they are rated at 5.6W each at 28V. The makeup mirror has a maximum rating label of 30W. Would the increase in wattage exceed this maximum rating? I know the bulbs are 28V so they'll be operating at less than their maximum but how do I work it out? Using P = VI?  Thanks.

Comment: The wattage rating is only a marginal increase (4.8W) I doubt it would make any difference. because overall, 4W @240V is 16.667 mA and 4.8W@240V is 20mA . .